# data-userid in Table causing Bootstrapper table sort to malfunction

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, bootstrap-table

```
    <table data-toggle="table" data-url="data2.json" data-search="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Delete</th>
            <th data-field="nameer" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
            <th data-field="email" data-sortable="true">Email</th>
            <th data-field="role" data-sortable="true">Role</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var user in Model.Users)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @if (Model.CurrentUserId != user.Id)
                    {
                        <a href="#" class="deleteUserLink" data-userid="@user.Id" data-name="@user.FullName">Delete</a>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <span>N/A</span>
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="editUserLink" data-userid="@user.Id">@user.FullName</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @user.Email
                </td>
                <td>
                    @string.Join(", ", user.Roles)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**ISSUE:**

With the above table the bootstrap sorting will function, however the field with data-userid will not sort correctly (in alphabetical order) while all the other ones without this will work fine.

I am new to stackoverflow, as well as bootstrapper. I hope I am providing enough information so you guys can help me. Thank you in advance.

I need the data-userid as it is being used in other areas, is there anyway to resolve this?

Comment: The fix for this was putting the data-name attribute before the data-userid. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sorter column option to define the custom sort of bootstrap table.

Here is an example: http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/index.html#options/custom-sort.html